# Determining the number of reduce slots in Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Using the Java API, how do I determine the current cluster's total number of reduce slots? (If I can get the number of slots *currently in use*, that would be a bonus.)

My use case: I have a Hadoop job that launches another Hadoop job. For the second job, I have to set the number of reducers. And this should be based on the number of slots available. Also, the cluster's size is subject to change.

I'm using Hadoop 2.7.3. And it normally runs on Amazon EMR, but I'd prefer a solution that just uses the Hadoop API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java HTTP client to request cluster metrics from YARN using [ResourceManager  REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Metrics_API).

The response will be a JSON containing total, allocated, reserved and available memory and vcores on the cluster.

```
$ curl -G -k https://<resource-manager-host>:8090/ws/v1/cluster/metrics
{"clusterMetrics":      
{"appsSubmitted":999999,"appsCompleted":999999,"appsPending":0,"appsRunning":99,"appsFailed":99,"appsKilled":999,
 "reservedMB":0,"availableMB":99999999,"allocatedMB":9999999,
"reservedVirtualCores":0,"availableVirtualCores":9999,"allocatedVirtualCores":9999,
"containersAllocated":9999,"containersReserved":0,"containersPending":999,
"totalMB":9999999,"totalVirtualCores":99999,
"totalNodes":999,"lostNodes":9,"unhealthyNodes":9,"decommissioningNodes":0,"decommissionedNodes":99,"rebootedNodes":0,"activeNodes":999}}
$
```

Not sure what you mean by "slots", because you can actually specify reducer container size when submitting MR job.

Comment: I think what I meant is "containers". "Slots" was the term that they used in older versions of Hadoop.

Comment: So as far as you know, there's no way to do this through the Java API? I have to make the HTTP request myself? If so, that brings up another question: how do I get the URL of the resource manager?

Comment: @MikeBaranczak The only other way I'm aware of is via JMX client if you configure and enable JMX on ResourceManager. But all things considered I find  RM's REST API super-easy and sufficient -- provides aggregated metrics from all NodeManagers, keeps tabs on schedulers and resource pools, tracks all the apps, etc. etc.

Comment: you can get RM host/port from `yarn-site.xml` config file.

Comment: OK, thanks. This looks like something I can use. A couple of clarifications: the relevant config property is `yarn.resourcemanager.address` (it contains the host and port). And looking for it in the *file* is pointless, since EMR overwrites this property - instead, check the configuration object that's visible in the job's context.

Comment: Right, config will probably* contain resolved host URL in case when RM is configured for high-availability... (* - not an expert on how exactly EMR implements HA.)